# BlackJack Basic Strategy

Tags: blackjack

I have been practicing basic strategy in BlackJack, and I have noticed that with every basic strategy chart I find that in terms of hard totals they all stop at 17. Why is this? And if I want to find my best course of action for a hard 18 (Jack, Queen King) and an 8, how would I figure this out? I'm sure there's something I'm certainly, missing, I'm just not sure what it is. Examples:

I am dealt a hard 18, King and 8. Blackjack basic strategy charts don't dictate how do this, why? and how do I figure this out?

I am dealt a hard 19, King and 9. Same questions as last time.

My chart is [Here](https://www.blackjackapprenticeship.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/BJA_Basic_Strategy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia's article for basic strategy says to **stand when dealt a hard 18-21, at all times, regardless of the dealer's face up card.**

Given a game with the following parameters:

1. Four to eight decks
2. The dealer hits on a soft 17
3. A double is allowed after a split
4. Only original bets are lost on dealer blackjack

[image]

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Basic_strategy
Source:  "4-Deck to 8-Deck Blackjack Strategy - Wizard of Odds". Wizard of Odds Consulting, Inc. Retrieved April 30, 2014. http://wizardofodds.com/games/blackjack/strategy/4-decks/